# TiKz. Angle between two vectors and a projection

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot, vector

I'm having trouble to draw something with TiKz. What I want to draw I think is simple:
[image: The graph]

SIM is a vector in the YZ-plane with a Beta = 38º, source is just a random vector with positive x and y components and negative z. Theta is the angle between SIM and source vectors and Phi is the angle formed by the source projection in the XZ-plane with the X-axis.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a `tikz-3dplot` approach. The arcs are drawn using:

```
% define three points
\tdplotdefinepoints(vx, vy, vz)(ax, ay, az)(bx, by, bz)
% draw arc using the three points and a radius
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[draw style]{r}{label options}{label}
```

The viewpoint can be modified using:

```
\tdplotsetmaincoords{rotation around x}{rotation around z}
```

The x-axis and z-axis can be exchanged using:

```
\let\raarotold\raarot \let\rbarotold\rbarot
\let\rabrotold\rabrot \let\rbbrotold\rbbrot
\let\racrotold\racrot \let\rbcrotold\rbcrot

\let\raarot\racrotold \let\rbarot\rbcrotold
\let\rabrot\rabrotold \let\rbbrot\rbbrotold
\let\racrot\raarotold \let\rbcrot\rbarotold
```

Note: The -z-axis in the following picture is actually the z-axis.
I have just changed the label.

See *Symbol 1's* [answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267359/18520) 
for details about coordinate system customization.

[image: tikz-3dplot - angle between vectors]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}

% customized coordinate system
\let\raarotold\raarot \let\rbarotold\rbarot
\let\rabrotold\rabrot \let\rbbrotold\rbbrot
\let\racrotold\racrot \let\rbcrotold\rbcrot

\let\raarot\racrotold \let\rbarot\rbcrotold
\let\rabrot\rabrotold \let\rbbrot\rbbrotold
\let\racrot\raarotold \let\rbcrot\rbarotold

\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

  % axes
  \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- ( 7,0,0) node[anchor=south]{$x$};
  \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- ( 0,7,0) node[anchor=west]{$y$};
  \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- ( 0,0,7) node[anchor=north east]{$-z$};  
  \draw[thick]    (0,0,0) -- ( 0,-2,0);
  \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- ( 0,0,-7) node[anchor=south west]{$z$};

  % vector 1
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ax}{5}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ay}{5}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\az}{2}
  \draw[very thick,->,red] (0,0,0) -- (\ax,\ay,\az) node[anchor=west]{source};

   % vector 2
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\bx}{0}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\by}{3}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\bz}{4}
  \draw[very thick,->,blue] (0,0,0) -- (\bx,\by,\bz) node[anchor=north]{sim};

   % vector 3 (projection)
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cx}{\ax*1.2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cy}{0}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cz}{\az*1.2}
  \draw[very thick,green] (0,0,0) -- (\cx,\cy,\cz);

   % dashed lines
%  \draw[dashed,gray] (\ax,\ay,\az) -- (\ax,\ay,0);
  \draw[dashed,gray] (\ax,\ay,\az) -- (\ax,0,\az);
  \draw[dashed,gray] (\ax,\ay,\az) -- (0,\ay,\az);
%  \draw[dashed,gray] (\ax,0,0) -- (\ax,\ay,0) -- (0,\ay,0);
  \draw[dashed,gray] (\ax,0,0) -- (\ax,0,\az) -- (0,0,\az);
  \draw[dashed,gray] (0,0,\az) -- (0,\ay,\az) -- (0,\ay,0);

  % arcs
  \tdplotdefinepoints(0,0,0)(\ax,\ay,\az)(\bx,\by,\bz)
  \tdplotdrawpolytopearc[<->]{2}{anchor=north west}{$\theta$}
  \tdplotdefinepoints(0,0,0)(0,0,1)(\bx,\by,\bz)
  \tdplotdrawpolytopearc[<->]{3}{anchor=north}{$\beta$}
  \tdplotdefinepoints(0,0,0)(1,0,0)(\cx,\cy,\cz)
  \tdplotdrawpolytopearc[<->]{4}{anchor=north}{$\phi$}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful solution. I always underestimate the *drawing* possibilities of `tikz-3dplot`. Is it possible to setup the axes like the OP had them in his question?

Comment: @PhilippImhof Thanks. The easiest  would be just to change the axis node labels. Rotating the axis is kind of tricky. I am trying to avoid it.

Comment: Sorry for asking (I could surely look it up in the manual, but maybe you know it right away): Is it another mechanism than in standard TikZ? Otherwise, you may try to copy the code from my example.

Comment: @PhilippImhof Many thanks for the hint! Axis configuration is described in section 2.1 "TikZ 3d Plotting" in the tikz-3dplot manual. Please see my edited answer. There is an issue though, `\tdplotdefinepoints`does not work as expected after changing the axis configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution, finally Phi was the projection of the vector source in a plane containing the X-axis and normal to vector SIM, I will try to understand the code and adapt it to that new definition

Answer (score 6):

This should do the job. Feel free to adapt the styles.

I suggest you define the coordinates of *source* individually, so that the projection onto the two planes and the axes can be done more easily. (The `let...in` syntax is not an option, because it does not work with 3d coordinates.)

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,angles,quotes,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[axes/.style={thick,->},
    z={(.5,{.5*sqrt(3)})},
    y={({.5*sqrt(3)},-.5)},
    x={(0,-.5,{.5*sqrt(3)})}]

   \draw[axes] (0,0,0) coordinate (O) -- (6,0,0) coordinate (X) node [right]{$x$};
   \draw[axes] (O) -- (0,6,0) node [above]{$y$};
   \draw[axes,<->] (0,0,-6) coordinate (Z') node [below left] {$-z$}
        -- (0,0,6) coordinate (Z) node [above right] {$z$} ;


   \pgfmathsetmacro{\sourcex}{5}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\sourcey}{5}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\sourcez}{-2}
   \coordinate (Source) at (\sourcex,\sourcey,\sourcez);
   \coordinate (Source on xz) at (\sourcex,0,\sourcez);
   \coordinate (Source on yz) at (0,5,-2);
   \coordinate (Source on xz) at (5,0,-2);
   \coordinate (Source on x axis) at (5,0,0);
   \coordinate (Source on y axis) at (0,5,0);
   \coordinate (Source on z axis) at (0,0,-2);

   \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0]
      \coordinate (SIM) at (-38:4);
   \end{scope}

   \draw[dotted] (\sourcex,0,\sourcez) -- (Source) -- (0,\sourcey,\sourcez);
   \draw[dotted] (\sourcex,0,0) -- (Source on xz) -- (0,0,\sourcez);
   \draw[dotted] (0,\sourcey,0) -- (0,\sourcey,\sourcez) -- (0,0,\sourcez);

   \pic [draw,angle radius=.6cm,angle eccentricity=1.4,"$\phi$"] 
        {angle = X--O--Source on xz};
   \pic [draw,angle radius=.5cm,angle eccentricity=1.5,"$\beta$"] 
        {angle = Z'--O--SIM};
   \pic [draw,fill=white,angle radius=.7cm,angle eccentricity=.6,"$\theta$"] 
        {angle = SIM--O--Source};

   \draw (O) -- (Source on xz);
   \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (Source) node[above right] {Source};
   \draw[->] (0,0) --  (SIM) node[below] {Sim};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can draw this shape in geogebra, and export it to tikz, easily. 
This is a sample:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\degre}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0.,0.39215686274509803,0.}
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0.,0.,1.}
\definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\draw [color=cqcqcq,dash pattern=on 3pt off 3pt, xstep=1.0cm,ystep=1.0cm] (-4.3,-2.66) grid (7.3,6.3);
\clip(-4.3,-2.66) rectangle (7.3,6.3);
\draw [shift={(1.,0.)},color=qqwuqq,fill=qqwuqq,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0) -- (-26.56505117707799:0.6) arc (-26.56505117707799:90.:0.6) -- cycle;
\draw (1.,3.)-- (1.,0.);
\draw (1.,0.)-- (5.,-2.);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=qqqqff] (1.,3.) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=qqqqff] (1.14,3.28) node {$A$};
\draw [fill=qqqqff] (1.,0.) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=qqqqff] (1.14,0.28) node {$B$};
\draw[color=black] (0.74,1.68) node {$a$};
\draw [fill=qqqqff] (5.,-2.) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=qqqqff] (5.14,-1.72) node {$C$};
\draw[color=qqwuqq] (2.64,0.44) node {$\alpha = 116.57\textrm{\degre}$};
\draw[color=black] (2.9,-1.12) node {$b$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```